# NestJS create new project failed on MacOS

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I'm currently using macOS 10.14.6(Mojave). When I started to create new nestjs by the cli `nest new prj`, I got this problem and can not figure out what happened? What is the problem and how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to parse HTML with regular expressions? Looks like you called Zalgo or Chtulu.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in colors.js. Nest uses this library to color the console info. Adding this in package.json should fix it:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "colors": "1.4.0"
  },
```

Read more about it here: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285

Comment: Version 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 of the dependency `colors` are malicious. They cause an infinite loop and print rubbish to the terminal. https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/commit/074a0f8ed0c31c35d13d28632bd8a049ff136fb6#diff-92bbac9a308cd5fcf9db165841f2d90ce981baddcb2b1e26cfff170929af3bd1R22

Answer (score 0):

Resolutions fix didn't seem to work for me. But this does:

```
npm install colors@1.4.0
```